# Does the LVM DM UUID contain any metadata?

Tags: redhat, lvm, uuid

For example within the name listed below is there any metadata within the name, eg based on server serial number or date created or such:

`dm-uuid-LVM-7Acc13lm0nUzEWXMNDfB4vBTyjGRtEbG13lq81vVyp1RtuXc3ASRkGHkU17BufdS`

The reason I ask is I know in AIX for example the PVID contains the machine ID of the system.

I did try looking through lvcreate.c from LVM2 toolset, however not being a C programmer it did not reveal much.